Does password bruteforcing decrease password's entropy?
So, I randomly sampled a password out of a space of $N$ many candidates, and handed its hash to an adversary.  My password's entropy is $\log_2N$ bits.
The adversary brute-forced the 1st half of passwords space, and found that my password is not there. This way, the adversary became sure that my password must be in the other half of the space.
My question is:

Did the adversary reduce my password's entropy from $\log_2N$ down to $\log_2\frac{N}{2}$ by brute-forcing half of the space?
Or did my password's entropy drop to $0$ immediately when the adversary knew its hash before even brute-forcing it?  Should we view the brute-forcing as just a computationally expensive decoding algorithm to decode the hash and the passwords' space to the chosen password?


That's an interesting question and it might be more subjective / opinionated as you may think, as I don't think this form of "entropy" has a generic definition. However, I see "the entropy of a key" more of a shorthand for "the amount of entropy used when generating the key". That would of course mean that the answer to both questions is both "no". The second one would be no even if this wasn't the case; usually you can also test a key if a ciphertext is known, and it would be weird if we then would say that the key would not have any entropy.

@MaartenBodewes Isn't entropy objectively defined by (in a sense) "the minimum number of binary questions that, if answered, we reveal the password"?  If we start from here, then I guess the question would become: "are we reducing the number of binary questions?". Then, can't we consider comparing password hashes as a mechanism of answering those binary questions? E.g. "is $\texttt{hash}(p_i) = \texttt{hash}(p)$?".

I don't know, but I'd use the big O notation for that, or a security in bits (remaining). I've never heard that an attack lowers the entropy in that sense. Of course, kodlu seems to use the term conditional entropy which seems well defined (and applicable) though I don't see it used much in cryptographic papers. Then again, I'm more in the applied cryptography corner and I don't read all papers related to this subject.

The uncertainty in the password with respect to the attacker's information is represented in terms of a conditional entropy.
Brute Force:
Let $X$ be your password, which takes values in $\{1,\ldots,N\}$ and if it's distributed uniformly, its unconditional entropy is
$$H(X)=\sum_{i=1}^N p_i \log(1/p_i)=\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{N} \log(N)=\log N$$
since the probability $p_i=Pr[X=i]=1/N,$ for all $i.$
Once the attacker has searched half the space, we use conditional entropy and apply the conditional probability. Say the keys searched were $\{N/2+1,N/2+2,\ldots,N\}$ and assume $N$ even for simplicity. This now means the new (conditional) distribution conditioned on the event $W$ of the attacker's search and its result is
$$ 
p_i=\left\{\begin{array}{ccl}2/N,&\quad& 1\leq i\leq N/2, \\
0 & & N/2+1\leq i\leq N. \end{array} \right.
$$
which will now give the value $H(X|W)=\log \frac{N}{2}.$
To anyone uninformed about this search the entropy does not change. If the attacker leaks the fact that the key is in the first half of the keyspace, then everyone's entropy can change.
Hash:
A good hash is difficult to invert, and it certainly does not reduce the entropy to zero when one hands the value of the hash to an attacker. Quantifying exactly what it becomes may be trickier. There is the question of the work factor. If it's a good hash, then birthday attack will apply and you need about $\sqrt{N}$ trials to obtain a value that gives that hash, but that still does not give you the value of the password.
But for an attacker, the value may not be important, just breaking the hash may be.

Just to confirm my understanding: it seems that you agree with the 1st option "entropy is reduced by 1 bit from $\log_2N$ down to $\log_2\frac{N}{2}$", but you add: finding the hash does not mean finding the password, due to the fact that password collisions exist.  Am I understanding right?

A follow-up question: what if I hand the adversary, not my password's hash $\texttt{hash}(p)$ but rather its losslessly compressed form $\texttt{zip}(p)$, would you still say that the entropy did not instantly reduce to 0 the moment I gave him $\texttt{zip}(p)$ and that the adversary had to 1st run $\texttt{unzip}\big(\texttt{zip}(p)\big)$ in order to finally reduce the entropy to zero?

Entropy cannot decrease with computation: it is defined in a statistical sense. If $p$ has $n$ bits of conditional min-entropy given $t$, then no transformation on $t$ (even inefficient) will allow me to guess $p$ with probability better than $2^{-n}$. Knowing the hash of $p$ can never allow me to guess $p$ with probability 1 since there are many preimages. Knowing $zip(p)$ allows me to guess $p$ with probability 1 since $p$ is uniquely determined by its compression.

@Kodlu answered your first question in the affirmative: halving the search space lowers the entropy about the password by 1 bit of entropy. Note that the uncertainty measure of importance here is the min-entropy, since it directly relates to the probability of guessing. In the case of the uniform distribution, it coincides with the Shannon entropy, so @Kodlu's answer is still valid.
I will try to answer the second question about the information provided by the hash of the password. Since hash functions are only computationally one-way and collision resistant, I will make the simplifying assumption that $h:[N]\rightarrow  [m]$ is a uniformly random function (also called the random oracle model).
I am not quite certain what you mean by "the adversary brute-forced the 1st half of passwords space", so I will consider two scenarios:

The adversary wants to find $p$ exactly; knows a subset $S$ of size $N/2$ which does not contain $p$ and knows $h(p)=t$.
The adversary wants to find a preimage of $h(p)$; knows $h(p)=t$ and knows $h(i)$ for $i\in S$ where $|S|=N/2$.

The second scenario is usually what we care about in practice: the password is hashed with a salt as $t=h(p,s)$ and $(t,s)$ is stored to authenticate the user. The attacker only needs to find $p'$ such that $h(p',s)=t$ to impersonate the user.
Scenario 1.
If the adversary knows $t=h(p)$, then it knows $p$ must be in the set $h^{-1}(t)$ which on average over $h$ has $N/m$ elements. Let $S\subset[N]$ be a subset of size $N/2$ such that the adversary knows that $p\notin S$. The adversary can conclude that $p\in \bar S\cap h^{-1}(t)$. Since $h$ is random, each $i\in\bar S$ is such that $h(i)=t$ with probability $1/m$. Therefore,  $\mathbb{E}_h|\bar S\cap h^{-1}(t)|=\frac N{2m}$. So the adversary gains $\log_2(2m)$ bits of information about $p$. The probability that the adversary can guess $p$ is $\frac {2m}N$.
Scenario 2.
The probability that the adversary does not find an $i\in S$ such that $h(i)=h(p)$ is
$$
\Pr[\forall i\in S, h(i)\neq t] \leq \left(1-\frac 1m\right)^{\frac N2}
$$
which goes to $0$ rapidly as $N$ grows. In other words, the adversary is overwhelmingly likely to find a $p'$ such that $h(p')=h(p)$. Computing $N/2$ hashes is overkill: as Kodlu mentions in his answer, having order of $\sqrt{N}$ hashes suffices to find a preimage with good probability.
